# Can this be the issue to my WordPress white screen?

Tags: wordpress

I got the white screen just a couple of days ago. First it only appeared randomly, but mostly when I wanted the save different changes in my admin panel.

Then I saw that `<b></b>` tag before the `DOCTYPE` tag. My site is [here](http://www.gainprofitincome.com).

I've deactivated some plugins but it still shows this error. I also checked the `functions.php` for white spaces and I can't come up with an answer.

Could this tag be the cause of the white screen? When I view the source for the white screen this is the only tag on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the logs to be sure what's going on..

In general, i can see 2 reasons for white screen:

1. PHP has crashed before it completed generating the page. This can be completely unrelated to the `<b></b>` tag. You will see some error messages in *php error log*.
2. PHP sends redirect headers **after** the `<b></b>` had been output - in this case the error will be *headers already sent*.

The `<b></b>` thing: seems that it is present on all pages of your site. I would advise to check files that are included in all pages. You may also run `grep -iRHn '<b></b>' ./` from the site's root directory.

Comment: I've got it to work. It seems the problem was with my theme. After renaming the theme folder my blog switched to the default theme and everything is fine now. That was also the cause of that '<b></b>' tag.

Comment: So it is the theme that screws things up - and there is the `<b></b>` in one of its files. After you renamed it, the WP can't find it any more and reverts to default.